# Are neighbourhood deformation retracts transitive?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have the following definition of a neighbourhood deformation retract (or NDR, for short): A pair $(X, A)$ is called an NDR if $A\subseteq X$ is closed and there exists a neighbourhood $A\subseteq V\subseteq X$ and a retraction $r: V\rightarrow A$, i.e. $r|_A=\mathrm{id}_A$ and there is a homotopy $H: V\times [0, 1]\rightarrow V$ such that $H(-, 0)=r, H(-, 1)=\mathrm{id}_V$ and $H|_{A\times [0, 1]}=\mathrm{pr}_A$.

Now I was wondering about the following: If $A\subseteq B$ is an NDR and $B\subseteq X$ is an NDR, does it follow that $A\subseteq X$ is an NDR? I suspect this is true, but somehow I cannot produce a proof.

I was trying to argue as follows: There is a neighbourhood $A\subseteq V\subseteq B$ and a retraction $r: V\rightarrow A$; moreover, there is a neighbourhood $B\subseteq W\subseteq X$ and a retraction $s: W\rightarrow B$. Now I want to choose $V'=s^{-1}(V)\subseteq X$ as a neighbourhood of $A$ in $X$ and use $r\circ s: V'\rightarrow A$ as a retraction. However, the problem is that I do not know whether the homotopy $H_s: W\times [0, 1]\rightarrow W$ between $s$ and $\mathrm{id}_W$ restricts to a homotopy $V'\times [0, 1]\rightarrow V'$, i.e. if it keeps points of $V'$ inside $V'$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Though this does not address the body of your post, the answer to your question is yes. A pair $(X,A)$ is an NDR, if and only if, $A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration. Its very easy to see cofibrations are closed under composition.

Comment: @ConnorMalin OPs definition of "NDR pair" is different from what usually gets called an NDR pair. Their definition neither implies nor is implied by being a cofibration.

Comment: @freakish But $V$ is a neighbourhood of $A$ in $B$, so since $s: W\rightarrow B$ is continuous, $s^{-1}(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $A$ in $W$, hence also in $X$, right?

Comment: @mxian ah, yes, my mistake.

Comment: I can give an affirmative answer under some assumptions that hold whenever $X$ is a CW complex or manifold.

Comment: @Tyrone Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, what I had in mind didn't quite work out.